# Set supported media commands for Google Cast Styled Media Receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

When using the [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver) with a queue, is it possible to add `QUEUE_NEXT` and `QUEUE_PREV` to the [supported media commands](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages.MediaStatus#supportedMediaCommands)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only customize via CSS. For the supported media commands you would need a custom receiver. By default the supported commands would be:

ALL_BASIC_MEDIA

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/web_receiver/cast.framework.messages#.ALL_BASIC_MEDIA

All basic media. Includes the mandatory commands and PAUSE, SEEK, STREAM_VOLUME, STREAM_MUTE. EDIT_TRACKS, PLAYBACK_RATE

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It looks like the most straightforward path to do what I need is to build out a basic web receiver (as shown at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/basic), and in the call to `.start()`, specify `supportedCommands` (as shown at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/core_features).  Does that sound accurate?  I'll experiment this weekend, thanks!